# using applescript in textwrangler to send code to julia

Tags: applescript

I am trying to setup a TextWrangler script that automatically sends selected code to Julia. Copying a bit from a similar script that does the job for sending code to R I tried the script

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    set the_selection to (selection of front window as string)

    if (the_selection) is "" then
        set the_selection to line (get startLine of selection) of front window as string
    end if
end tell

tell application "Julia-0.2.1"
    activate
    cmd the_selection
end tell
```

It does not work. Probably because of the line containing "cmd the_selection". Anyone a suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if Julia isn't scriptable as @khagler says, then you can usually use gui scripting. This will work as long as Julia has an edit menu and the keyboard shortcut for paste is cmd-v (like in most applications) and your cursor is placed in the proper location for the paste to work. Good luck.

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    set the_selection to (selection of front window as string)

    if (the_selection) is "" then
        set the_selection to line (get startLine of selection) of front window as string
    end if
end tell

set the clipboard to the_selection

tell application "Julia-0.2.1" to activate
delay 0.2
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```

***EDIT***: I see in your comments that a new Julia window opens every time the script is run. That might be happening because of the line... tell application "Julia" to activate. You might try this line of code in its place. It's another method to bring Julia frontmost before issuing the keystroke commands.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Julia-0.2.1" to set frontmost to true
```

Note that if this doesn't bring the Julia window frontmost then it's because the process name is wrong. Sometimes the process name is different than the application name. If true you'll have to figure out the name of the Julia process which you can do by running this and finding its name. You may have to use "Terminal" if Julia runs in a Terminal window.

```
tell application "System Events" to return name of processes
```

Comment: Thanks both of your for all the help. Regulus' solution almost does what I want. It opens up Julia and pastes the line. Of course I would like to have an enter (to execute the command) added to that. If I send a second line to julia with this script, then a new terminal with julia opens. Of course I wish to have all code pasted in one terminal. Can the script be adjusted for that?

Comment: Well now it's up to you to tweak the code. I think you can see where I issued the cmd-v. If the execute command also has a keyboard shortcut you can issue it in a similar manner after the cmd-v. Regarding the new window opening, that might be because of the "activate" command. See the EDIT portion of my code for a different method of bringing Julia to the front.

Comment: One more thing... if my response answers your question, please mark (by checking it) my response as the answer so others know you have found a solution. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I got it running now. Thank you so much! As Julia runs in a Terminal I just had to change process Julia-0.2.1 to Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Julia is not scriptable, so you won't be able to send your code this way. You could try this:

```
do shell script "julia -e '" & the_selection & "'"
```

This is equivalent to typing a command into a Terminal window. Depending on what exactly is in your selection, you might need to save it as a file first and then pass the file path instead. Also, note that if julia is not in your path (as would be the case if you just copied the Julia app to your Applications folder) you'll need to specify the full path to the actual executable within the .app package: `/Applications/Julia-0.2.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. TextWrangler says "A scripting error has occurred: Julia-0.2.1 got an error: Connection is invalid". (Julia activates, but nothing is executed)

Comment: Did you put that line inside the tell block for TextWrangler? It should be outside, entirely replacing the tell block for Julia.

Comment: I now put it outside and get another scripting error "sh: julia command not found"

Comment: That means that julia isn't in your path so you need to use a full path to wherever it is. Assuming that you've put the Julia app in your Applications folder, that would be a path like this: `/Applications/Julia-0.2.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia`.

Comment: Yes, that's where it is located. So I now have after the tell block for TextWrangler do shell script "/Applications/Julia-0.2.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia -e '" & the_selection & "'" Now I get "r "sh: Julia.0.2.1: command not found" number 127". Strange..